# Entity Framework: List<T> how to hook into entity.PropertyChanged

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Is there a better way to hook into the PropertyChanged?

```
List<VisitorHost> _hosts = context.VisitorHosts.Where(a => a.Clients_Id == client.Id).Where(a => a.Inactive == false).ToList();
foreach (VisitorHost vh in _hosts)
   {  
   vh.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler (visitorhost_PropertyChanged);
   }
```

This _hosts is attached to a BindingSource:

```
visitorhostBindingSource.DataSource = _hosts;
```

The BindingSource is attached to a DataGridView:

```
visitorHostsDataGridView.DataSource = visitorhostBindingSource;
```

All I'm trying to do is Enable the Save and RollBack buttons (and set a flg so it reminds me to save if I move away), seems like what I am doing is very basic, but I just don't know the answer.

```
void visitorhost_PropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
   if (!flgLoading) // Don't update if initialization
      {
      SetModified ();  // turn on buttons and update Flag for parent container 
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can't you hook into `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` in stead? Otherwise you'd also have to unhook your entities whenever the grid content changes.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't activate until you activate another cell.  IE you can't edit a value then click save because it doesn't see the cell value has changed until you leave.

Comment: That's actually a problem with the solution I am using now, BTW.

Comment: I'm thinking that CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged might be the ticket.  Not sure I like that any better though.